# BIGQUERY TIMEZONE conversion on TIMESTAMP. CET to UTC

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp, utc

I am storing one timestamp column in Bigquery table.  The source is of CET timestamp.  But bigquery is storing it by default in UTC.

How to store it as CET timestamp?  otherwise while fetching if also I am doing the timestamp conversion it is manipulating the timestamp value. that I do not want.

Or else I want to convert the value to UTC while fetching but for that I have to make Bigquery understood that the original column is in CET format.  How to resolve this?

Comment: there are too many hickups to convert and maintain this in CET, my suggestion is to strore and load in UTC then reading out in other timezone is easy you have example from documentation

Comment: I agree with @Pentium10. CET, and the summer CEST, is a nightmare to manage. Store uniformly all your time (in UTC, in UTC+1 if you prefer), but keep the same rule.